# Regex pattern to identify the exact file name

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find a pattern(Regex) to find the exact regex to find the name of a file.I was trying the pattern as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]([a-zA-Z0-9])` to find the folder names named as

```
01_ABC Documents(AX050-AX070)
```

But names like "Forms" also finds true with the pattern.One thing additionally i want to check is to ensure there is no space between "Documents" and starting of parenthesis"(". If it has a space I should fail it as well. For an example I should fail file names like
 `01_ABC Documents (AX050-AX070)`
I was trying to build a pattern using http://regexr.com/ site. But unable to build the exact pattern. Please help me to find a pattern for this.

Comment: Are you trying to find the suffix the AX050-AX070? I would do someting like / [A-Z]{2}\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}\d{3}/

Comment: Thanks  what you have done is correct. I need one step ahead.Actually I want to add a Space to the starting of the parenthesis. So finding the files which does not have a space between parenthesis and the word "Documents"

Comment: Please clearly state what you need to match: I've **this** and I need **this**

Comment: @PedroLobito I have updated the question.

Comment: Is `Documents` a constant ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Yes it is a constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use something like:

```
[0-9]+_[A-Z]+\sDocuments+\([A-Z0-9]{5}-[A-Z0-9]{5}\)
```

You can make the regex case insensitive by using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`